# Sqoop: ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error reading from database: java.sql.SQLException:

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hadoop, sqoop

When I am trying to import data from mysql to HDFS using Sqoop and running the following command

> *sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://IP Address/database name
>   --username root --password password --table table name --m 1*

I am getting the below error

> *ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error reading from database:
>   java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set
>   com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@555b6c34 is still active. No statements
>   may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a
>   given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active
>   streaming result sets before attempting more queries.*

I am unable to understand what it is and browsed many websites for solutions but did not even got a clue.

Please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqoop import issue with mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162447/sqoop-import-issue-with-mysql)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try mentioning driver name, It worked for me

```
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Worked for me. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

a quick google search on your exception gives me an impression that this was a bug reported in sqoop. It looks like they have resolved it. Please look at this `https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1400`.

Verify your sqoop and mysql connector version and update to newer version if required. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Satha, I got it resolved by upgrading to the newer version of mysql connector

Answer (score 2):

My issue was resolved after using:

```
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

in sqoop script.

e.g.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://IP Address/database name --username root --password password --table table name --m 1 --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```