# sqoop import issue with mysql

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, sqoop

I have a hadoop ha setup based on cdh5.I have tried to import tables from mysql  by using sqoop failed with following error.

```
15/03/20 12:47:53 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error reading from database: java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@33573e93 is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@33573e93 is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
```

I have used the below command..

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://<mysql hostname>:3306/haddata --username root --password password --table authors --hive-import
```

My mysql server version is  5.1.73-3. and used 5.1.34 and 5.1.17 version of mysql-connector-java

```
sqoop version is 1.4.5-cdh5.3.2
```

Please let me know any suggestion/comments.

Answer (score 27):

Try including the option --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in the import command.

Comment: Worked for me...Thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

Try using the below modified command, which can suit your purpose

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://<mysql hostname>:3306/haddata --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --username root --password password --table authors --hive-import
```

Answer (score 7):

[follow this link](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/4822/hdp-232-sandbox-sqoop-error-stating-no-statements-1.html)

Include the driver argument `--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in sqoop command.

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://<mysql hostname>:3306/<db name>  --username **** --password **** --table <table name> --hive-import --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

The --driver parameter forces sqoop to use the latest mysql-connector-java.jar installed for mysql db on the sqoop machine

Answer (score 2):

Try with  mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar, it is compatable with sqoop 1.4.5.

mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar driver does not work with sqoop 1.4.5.

refer :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1400

Answer (score 0):

If you have com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar or any version of com.mysql.jdbc_5.X.X.jar file in $HADOOP_HOME/bin folder, then remove that, and execute your SQOOP query.

Answer (score 0):

including the option --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in the import command worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop does not ship with third party JDBC drivers. You must download them separately and save them to the /var/lib/sqoop/ directory on the server.

Note:
The JDBC drivers need to be installed only on the machine where Sqoop runs. You do not need to install them on all hosts in your Hadoop cluster.

You can download driver from here : https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the exact command as like below.

> sqoop import  --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books" 
>   --username=root  --password=root --table authors --as-textfile --target-dir=/datasqoop/authors_db  --columns "id, name, email" --split-by id --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

This will resolve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Find the jar locations that are being used in sqoop, in my case, it is pointing to the link /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar

so when I check the link /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar it points to mysql-connector-java-**5.1.17**.jar

> /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar -> mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar

as 5.1.17 is having this issue, try **5.1.37 or higher**.

> unlink /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
>
> ln -s /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar