# Sqoop iMport Issues

Tags: sqoop

I have installed recent cloudera cluster CDH5.5 Single node and i am facing below error while importing db from mysql to hdfs.
am able to run list-dtabases commaned successfully.
Please let me know the root cause for the below issue.

> [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sqoop import  --connect
>   "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/nvegesn" --username root  --password XXXX
>   --table products Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail. Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of
>   your Accumulo installation. 15/12/10 20:14:00 INFO sqoop.Sqoop:
>   Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.5.0 15/12/10 20:14:00 WARN
>   tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is
>   insecure. Consider using -P instead. 15/12/10 20:14:01 INFO
>   manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
>   15/12/10 20:14:01 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
>   15/12/10 20:14:01 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement:
>   SELECT t.* FROM `products` AS t LIMIT 1 15/12/10 20:14:01 ERROR
>   manager.SqlManager: Error reading from database:
>   java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set
>   com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@47d0ac94 is still active. No statements
>   may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a
>   given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active
>   streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
>   java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set
>   com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@47d0ac94 is still active. No statements
>   may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a
>   given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active
>   streaming result sets before attempting more queries.     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:934)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:931)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkForOutstandingStreamingData(MysqlIO.java:2735)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1899)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2619)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2569)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1524)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMaxBytesPerChar(ConnectionImpl.java:3003)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Field.getMaxBytesPerCharacter(Field.java:602)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData.getPrecision(ResultSetMetaData.java:445)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:286)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:227)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:327)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1834)
>     at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1646)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
>     at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
>     at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)    at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)   at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)    at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)    at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236) 15/12/10 20:14:01 ERROR
>   tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job:
>   java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter

Comment: There is a related stackoverflow post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162447/sqoop-import-issue-with-mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162447/sqoop-import-issue-with-mysql) hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Abhi hoowever as am not able to change SQL connector Jar present in Cloudera Cluster.

Comment: Its working fine after adding driver also in command  as below sqoop import --connect "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/nvegesn" --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  --username root --password XXXX --table products

Answer (score 0):

Incase if the table you are trying to import doesn't have primary key then try giving 'm 1' towards then end. This will trigger only one mapper.

By default sqoop will fire 4 mappers. In this case it might not know on which column range the data needs to split across 4 mappers.
 Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Abhi, Still facing the same and i have created table with primary key only.i could see this is fixed in patch SQOOP-1400 which issue is with sql connector hoever i am not able to edit anything in cloudera machine.